# React functional component, how to re-render after data is removed

Tags: reactjs

Trying to remove an item from the database from a list view with a button.

The data gets removed on click, but the component isnt removed from the page.

How should I go about making it re-render after its removed?

I an not using redux for this

```
const EmailItem = ({email}) => (

  <div>
    <h3>{email}</h3>
    <button
      onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      axios.delete("/api/emails/delete/", {
        data: {email: email}
      })
      }
    }
    >
      Remove
  </button>
  </div>
)
```

export default (EmailItem)

Comment: this seems like a problem for the flux pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a handler/callback in props as onDelete from parent. Calling onDelete inside axios success would call the callback body defined in parent... where essentially you would be having conditional state to show or hide this component.

```
Parent extends React.component {
constructor {
    this.state={
      showEmail: true
    }
}
hideEmail =()=>this.setState({showEmail:false})
render(){
this.state.showEmail && {
<EmilItem onDelete={hideEmail} email = {your email}/>
}
}
```

and then change your existing EmailItem to:

```
const EmailItem = ({email, onDelete}) => (
```

and handler to:

```
onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault();   

axios.delete("/api/emails/delete/",    { data: {email: email} }).then(){
onDelete()
} }
```

Comment: Yes, in that case EmailItem component does not control the state responsable to update render on the screen. So you must pass some function parameter to make a callback triggered by button click and remove the email content. Good example!

Comment: Wont changing the state of the parent component hide all the EmailItem components?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I cant get this to work.

Comment: When I add the promise it gives an error, when I remove the promise it changes state to false and hides all emailitems.

Comment: @vijay any ideas?

Comment: @sierra could you please provide any code sample where I can see it running and help you fix the issue.